# Сумма списка произвольных элементов

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, типы

Получил вот такую задачку:

> Написать функцию, которая вычисляет сумму списка аргументов
>   произвольной длины с разными типами элементов списка.

Не знаю, как передать  в функцию произвольное количество элементов, тем более разных типов.

Comment: Помимо этого, есть у меня проблема в обработке этого произвольного количества аргументов. Не понятно, как их в цикл загонять.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Если еще интересует - гляньте еще на один вариант решения - в Update моего ответа...

Comment: @Harry, что происходит? Почему у меня полная лента вашего некропостинга? Вас захватили роботы?

Comment: @gbg Что-то вы сегодня в раздражении :( И [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1147348/195342), и сейчас... А может, я захотел медаль археолога получить? :)

Comment: @Harry, нет, о вас беспокоюсь, думал, у вас учетку угнали - за короткое время куча правок из прошлого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Произвольное количество аргументов, можно передать при помощи троеточия. Как перебрать все аргументы, смотрите [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/). Но чтобы воспользоваться этим решением типы аргументов нужно знать, потому вам это не подходит. Вам помогут **variadic templates**, которые появились в C++11. Перебрать все аргументы циклом не получится, вам нужна рекурсия:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class R, class T>
R summ(const T &arg){
    return arg;
}

template<class R, class T, class ...Args>
R summ(const T &arg, const Args &...args){
    return summ<R>(args...) + arg;
}

int main(){
    char c = 1;
    short s = 2;
    int i = 3;
    double d = 4;
    long l = 5;
    std::cout << summ<int>(c, s, i, d, l); //15
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Разве что вот такая жуть?

```
template <typename ...P> struct sum_type;

template <typename T>
struct sum_type<T>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, typename ...P>
struct sum_type<T, P...>
{
    using type = decltype(T()+typename sum_type<P...>::type());
};

template <typename ...P>
using sum_type_t = typename sum_type<P...>::type;


template <typename T>
inline T sum(T t) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename ...P>
inline sum_type_t<T, P... > sum(T t, P... p)
{
    return t + sum(p...);
}
```

Подсмотрено в *Discovering Modern C++* Готтшлинга.

Просто передать в функцию что угодно можно с помощью трех точек :) - типа `sum(double a, ...)`, но распознать внутри функции разные типы без шаблонов - что-то не вижу такой возможности.

**Update** Вот еще одно решение:

```
template <typename T>
inline T sum(T t) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename ...P>
inline auto sum(T t, P... p)
{
    return [](auto a, auto b) { return a + b; }(t,sum(p...));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(2, 2.5, ' ', false) << std::endl;
}
```