# Подскажите, как решить с помощью лямбда-выражения задачу

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Подскажите как решить с помощью ЛЯМБА-ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ задачку:
Написать функцию, которая вычисляет сумму списка аргументов произвольной длины с разными типами элементов списка.(Так понятно как ее решать, но надо именно лямбду вставить).

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <utility> 
#include<functional> 

template <class T>
T sum(T&& t)
{ 
    return t; 
} 

template <class T, class... Args> 
auto sum(T&& t, Args&&... args)->decltype(t + sum(std::forward<Args> args)...))
{
    return (t + sum(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
} 

template <class T, class... Args> 
using KUnaryType = std::function < T(T, Args...) >; 

int main()
{
    auto h = sum(2, 2.5, ' ', false); 
    std::cout << h << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Код без лямбда-выражения.

Comment: А покажите код, который у вас есть на текущий момент.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include<functional>
template <class T>
T sum(T&& t)
{
 return t;
}
template <class T, class... Args> 
auto sum(T&& t, Args&&... args)->decltype(t + sum(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){ return (t + sum(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
template <class T, class... Args>
using KUnaryType = std::function < T(T, Args...) > ;
template <class T, class... Args>
KUnaryType<T, Args...> My_sum = [](){};
int main()
{
 auto h = sum(2, 2.5, ' ', false);

 std::cout << h<< std::endl;
 return 0;
}

Comment: Там под вопросом есть кнопка «править», лучше внесите в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Придумался вариант такой...

```
template <typename T>
inline T sum(T t) { return t; }

template <typename T, typename ...P>
inline auto sum(T t, P... p)
{
    return [](auto a, auto b) { return a + b; }(t,sum(p...));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum(2, 2.5, ' ', false) << std::endl;
}
```

Да, шаблоны + лямбды - это сила покруче кардинала и галантерейщика :)

И никакого описания возвращаемого типа в духе решения к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566295/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Harry, you are super!