# Почему не берется адрес первого элемента массива?

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть массив:

```
char a[2] = { '1','4' };
cout <<&a<<" "<< &a[0] <<" "<<  &a << endl; /вывод:
```

Почему когда я пишу &a[0] то у меня выводится весь массив,только на конце еще 0?

И еще такой вопрос,почему в функцию RegQueryValueEx мы передаем адрес адреса массива((LPBYTE)&keyData)?Ведь имя массива должно неявно к указателю на этот массив преобразовываться.

```
   HKEY hKey;
   TCHAR keyData[256] = { 0 };
   DWORD keysize = sizeof(keyData);
   RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Key", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&keyData, &keysize);
```

P.S.. Давай,stackoverflow,минуси мои вопросы,как всегда,это же проще делать чем помогать новичкам.

Comment: На эти два вопроса будут два разных ответа - именно поэтому их следует разделить. И тег winapi к первому вопросу не имеет отношения. Если вы, новичок, хотите развиваться в сторону профессионального программирования, вам следует научиться мыслить системно.

Comment: 1. У нас не форум, а "Сервис вопросов и ответов". 
2. Даже на местечковом форуме имеются правила оформления и ведения тем, чтобы информация на форуме была полезна широкой аудитории, а не только задавшему вопрос. Тех, кто эти правила игнорирует, ожидает закономерное выпроваживание с ресурса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так уж определен оператор `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const char*);` чтобы выводить массив символов так же, как и выводится в `С`. Поскольку известно, что символьный массив заканчивается символом '\0', то любая функция может определить его конец, поэтому есть смысл сразу выдать массив.

Имя массива используется как указатель на первый элемент, поэтому `cout <<a и  cout << &a[0]` это одно и то же.
Но, так как в своем массиве вы не оставили место для `'\0'`, то и получать можете неопределенный результат_будут выводится все байты, пока в памяти не встретится байт с нулевым значением.

LPBYTE это указатель(длинный указатель), а указатели могут содержать только адреса объектов, поэтому нужно передавать адрес, с последующим преобразованием в (LPBYTE), и получается: `(LPBYTE)&keyData`, но так как `keyData` имя массива, и передается как указатель, то правильно будет: `(LPBYTE)keyData`. Другое дело, если функция сама принимает указатель по ссылке...

Пожалуйста, впредь старайтесь в одном вопросе не включать несколько вопросов. Просто оформляйте их как разные вопросы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110061/discussion-on-answer-by-ar-hovsepyan-------).